# How to make selected button highlighted?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have four buttons. I want that selected button keep highlighted till other button is selected. After that other button gets highlighted and first button unhighlighted.

```
- (void)doHighlight:(UIButton*)b {

   [b setHighlighted:YES];  

 }
-(IBAction)sizeBtnClicked:(UIButton*)btn{

     [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:btn afterDelay:0];

}
```

My problem is after selecting other button first button does not unhighlight.please guide me how to do it.

Comment: use images instead for background and change them as when required to show a particular state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a variable button `tempBtn` in your .h , alloc it and then perform this.

```
-(IBAction)sizeBtnClicked:(UIButton*)btn{
         [tempBtn setHighlighted:NO];
         [btn setHighlighted:YES];
         tempBtn=btn ;
        [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:btn afterDelay:0];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply get the reference of last selected button
and then in the sizeBtnClicked, set the highlighted property of last selected button to NO.

Answer (score 0):

In nib file you can change a image for button selection in inspector